# i want to run sql queries or commands using oracle xe 18c dbms

Tags: database, oracle

I want to run sql queries and commands in oracle xe dbms 18c windows version but cant find that option from where the sql command line interface could get opened

Answer (score 1):

Command line tool is called **SQL*Plus**. Open operating system command prompt window (CMD on Windows) and type `sqlplus` (optionally, provide connect string) and hit ENTER.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ╚et Ruj 26 08:50:38 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Alternatively, download & install **SQL Developer**, a free GUI tool developed by Oracle. You can find it at the same place where you found the database - OTN download section.